# SQL Server Rowcount of column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a simple SQL code that can get the desired output, from this table -

Original Table :

```
id | type
123  0
123  1
123  1
345  0
345  0
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
id | zeroCount | oneCount
123     1          2
345     2          0
```

I tried to `group by` the id and also type but, both of them gives the same thing!

How to get desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple way, assuming the values are only 0 and 1:

```
select id, sum(1 - type) as zerocount, sum(type) as onecount
from t
group by id;
```

A more typical approach would use `case` (or even `pivot`):

```
select id, sum(case when type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as zerocount,
       sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as onecount
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get fancy and use a pivot function.  But this will work:

```
Select id, 
 sum(case when type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as ZeroCount,
 Sum(case when type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as OneCount
 from table
group by id
order by id
```